# issues with delete document function with firebase firestore (code runs, document still exists in firestore) - React / Typescript / Redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, redux-thunk

as per title, I am not sure if I am doing something wrong but I am unable to delete a document with my code; despite the code appearing to run without hiccup. I can confirm that the document ID exists within the firestore, there is also no subcollections in it (as I understand delete works weirdly with subcollections).

Code here

delete function

```
export const deletePost = (
  docId: string,
  community: string
): AppThunk => async (
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  dispatch
): Promise<void> => {
  console.log(
    await firebase.firestore().collection(community).doc(docId).get()
  );

  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection(community)
    .doc(docId)
    .delete()
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
      dispatch(
        alertSuccess("post deleted, reverting to community page", "success")
      );
      dispatch(retrievePostsByCommunity(community));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
    });
  dispatch({ type: DELETE_POST });
};
```

firebase rules (its a very simple and basic setup)

```
 rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write, update, delete: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2029, 12, 21);
    }
  }
}
```

image of the collection if relevant

Thank you!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfRhm.png

Answer (score 0):

silly mistake in the args for the method... managed to get it to work.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: to make this answer useful to OTHERS - can you add the details of the mistake, so other readers can learn as well?

Comment: Hi,

it was just a simple mistake of misarranging the args

i.e. 

the method was defined as deletePost(docId, community)

I had implemented it as deletePost(community, docId)

thanks!